# a web spider,some method or idea for catch aynamic web page?

Tags: javascript, web-crawler

there are many web spider,but they just catch the html form internet. i want a web spider,some method or idea for catch aynamic web page,and can exec javascript,and i can get information form the dom tree.

Comment: It isn't very clear what your question is. Please try to make your problem or question clear. Also, it might be a good idea to run a quick spell check (eg, “aynamic”?)

Answer (score 0):

The more you'll want your spider to behave like a real browser the more you'll need a real browser; so, I recommend starting with a headless browser like [Crowbar](http://simile.mit.edu/wiki/Crowbar). From it's description:

> [Crowbar's] purpose is to allow running javascript scrapers against a DOM to automate web sites scraping but avoiding all the syntax normalization issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with Java, you can try Http Unit http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/
HttpUnit is very intuitive and easy to use. Its was made for web application Unit Testing, but it can be very powerful tool for web crawling. It has integrated engine for JavaScript. Also it comes bundled with many useful libs.